# How to display name of the user who ran a macro in a specific cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm not too tech savvy, I apologize, hence me asking this but, would anyone know how to display the user who ran a macro in a specific cell in google sheets? No anonymous users to worry about, I'm hoping to log who runs a certain macro for records purposes.

Comment: How are you wanting to store this? You can edit the Macro to append the username and edited cell to a file or even email it to an address so it depends on how you want this implemented.

Comment: hello, the intention is to just populate it in a target cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current user’s email address by calling the App Script `Session.getActiveUser` method and then using `arguments.callee.name` you can get the name of which Macro was used.

You can append this code to the end of your Macro function:

```
  // get email of user that ran the macro
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()

  //Set cell to add value to, in this case Sheet2:A1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1);

  cell.setValue(user + ' ran macro ' + arguments.callee.name);
```

You just need to specify which Cell to write the information to.

Comment: Wow! this was exactly what i was looking for! thanks sooo much :)